# strange issue between php and jquery plugin

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to make a dynamic website that loads data from a mysql database
Ive also used this [jquery slider](http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/)

following is the html markup that works perfectly

```
<div id="carousel">
                <img src="images/002.jpg" />
                <img src="images/003.jpg" />
                <img src="images/004.jpg" />
                <img src="images/005.jpg" />
                <img src="images/006.jpg" />
                <img src="images/007.jpg" />
                <img src="images/008.jpg" />
                <img src="images/009.jpg" />
                <img src="images/010.jpg" />
            </div>
            <a href="#" id="ui-carousel-next"><span></span></a>
            <a href="#" id="ui-carousel-prev"><span></span></a>
```

now I have stored the image urls in a database and want to fetch them and use them here with php so I did the following

```
echo "/*other markup code for the page which finally ends with this*/     
<div id=\"carousel\">";

        $image_name = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images where category = 'current' ");
        $image_url = array();

        while( $image_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_name) )
        {
            $image_url[] = $image_row['url'];
        }

        $image_number = count($image_url);
$idi = 0;

        while($idi<$image_number)
    {
        echo "
                <img src=\""."$image_url[$idi]"."\" />";
                $idi++;
    }

    echo "</div>
            <a href=\"#\" id=\"ui-carousel-next\"><span></span></a>
            <a href=\"#\" id=\"ui-carousel-prev\"><span></span></a>
*/other markup code for the page*/";
```

with this done the slider just wont work, what I get is an error saying

```
TypeError: data.lastPage[i] is undefined
    if ( data.lastPage[i].get(0) === page[i].get(0) ) {
```

which is the plugin file.

I tried playing around with how I divide the data to be echoed and noticed if

```
<div id="carousel">
```

is echoed seperately while

```
<image src="image_source" />
</div>
```

are echoed together it works, however if I try to separate these two, bang comes the error...

Comment: Take a look at the source code when you try it either way, and see if you can spot the difference. Also, the way you have your image line formatted, you don't need the quotes around $image_url[$idi].

Comment: the quotes are for concatenation.. and I tried looking at the source after the page renders. It didnt show any errors. I'll try taking a closer look though.

Comment: You don't need them form concatenation when it's just a variable inside. Only the periods.  <img src=\"".$image_url[$idi]."\" /> will work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You are echoing the variable `$image_url[$idi]` in a wrong way at this part:

```
while($idi<$image_number)
{
    echo "
            <img src=\""."$image_url[$idi]"."\" />";
            $idi++;
}
```

The above code should be this:

```
while($idi<$image_number)
{
    echo "
            <img src=\"".$image_url[$idi]."\" />";
            $idi++;
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it hasn't made any difference. What's more when I check the source it shows the img code correctly, however if I look at the source through firebug, the code seems to be missing

Answer (score -2):

I think your problem is here

```
while( $image_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_name) )
    {
        $image_url[] = $image_row['url'];
    }
```

This just sets your array to contain the character string 'url' and nothing more. To correct this, adjust it to this:

```
while( $image_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($image_name) )
    {
        $image_url[] = $image_row["url"];
    }
```

"url" will coordinate with the associated value in the column named url. Row and Column ID's are stored in MySQL as whole strings and not character strings.

Also, this is just me, but have you checked your source code after loading the page? If you are google chrome, the dev tools have an exception counter to find these errors and it provides solutions.

Comment: When dealing with associative arrays, it doesn't matter what kind of quotes you use

Comment: Alright, my bad. It would be worth checking to see the constructed source code after the php is executed then.